# Finding out the data type of a variable in XSLT/XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

It seems that the xpath `instance of` and `castable as` operators provide me with a boolean result for a guess... In other words, i cannot find a way to discover the type of a variable without previously guessing it with an "yes or no" condition.

Let's say that I have no ideia what the type is, all I can do is ask if variable `$x` has the data type of `xs:string`, or if is actually an `xs:integer`, etc, for all possible xslt datatypes, without getting a direct answer.

```xml
  <xsl:function name="findType">
    <xsl:param name="var"/>
    <xsl:choose test="not(string(.) castable as xs:integer)">
     <xsl:when test="$var instance of xs:integer">
        <xsl:value-of select="'xs:integer'" />
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="$var instance of xs:string">
         <xsl:value-of select="'xs:string'" />
     </xsl:when>
     ...
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="'unknown'" />
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>
```

Is there a way to directly get the datatype of a variable, without the switch-case?

Comment: See the functions http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_sequence-type.html, http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_node-kind.html and http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_atomic-type.html of the functx library of the options you have.

Comment: As you have also used the tag for [tag:saxon], in the commercial editions you have http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/type.html and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/type-annotation.html.

Comment: The functx library did it for me. Feel free to post an answer if you wish so. Thanks!

Comment: Do note that XSLT 2.0+ stylesheet functions allows either this "dynamic typing" or the most used "static typing" with `as` attribute set. Generally, when you go down the dynamic road, you are delaying the type check to some later mechanism as dynamic method invocation (ie. "duck typing"), pattern matching (yes, like XSLT) or "type promotion/subtype substitution" as in XPATH. So, it's not clear what is your use case.

Comment: TL;DR: I was printing the types just for experimental purposes. I was confused with a function returning an unexpected type (i was using a `value-of` when i should really be using a `sequence`), so I wanted to check those types by printing them on some section of the document itself, just to see what was going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the approach taken in the three functions `functx:node-kind` http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_node-kind.html, `functx:atomic-type` http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_atomic-type.html and `functx:sequence-type` http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_node-kind.html of the functx library http://www.xsltfunctions.com/.

Specific to the commercial editions (PE and EE of Saxon) you can also find http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/type-annotation.html and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/type.html useful.

Comment: @EvandroTeixeira Unless you are printing this nominals data types or maybe writing schemas, you will be using conditional expressions against those types. It is still not clear what is the use case.

Answer (score 3):

In general, an XDM value belongs to an arbitrary number of types and it's meaningless to ask what "the type" is. This becomes most obvious with XPath 3.0 maps, where it becomes very clear that the type system is a lattice rather than a hierarchy.

With the vast majority of commonly-used values, however, there's a fairly intuitive notion of "the most specific user-visible type" of an item, and it's because this notion is intuitive rather than formal that you find it provided by extension functions rather than a built-in function. (Another reason is that types aren't first-class objects in XDM, so it's unclear how to represent the answer to the question "what is the type of X?").

A further objection to this functionality is that it can be easily misused. Asking `if (typeof(X) == decimal) ...` would give the result "false" if X is an integer, despite integer being a subtype of decimal. If the implementation of `abs(X)` changes so that it returns an integer when X is an integer, then existing code that asks whether the result is a decimal is going to break. The "instance of" operator is much safer.

Comment: "Lattice rather than a hierarchy" is a great concept.

Comment: My mistake was really supposing that it was indeed a hierarchy and that it somehow could give me the last children of the type-inheritance hierarchy (kinda like the Java `instance of `would do). Glad to know it was not the case. Very insightful answer!